# m3u8 HLS Streaming not working in Android OS versions 6.0(M) and 5.0(L)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, http-live-streaming, m3u8, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I am using MediaPlayer for Live steaming the Video using HLS medium. 
The streaming file has extension .m3u8. The multimedia file is not able to provide streaming in Android OS versions MarshMallow and Lollipop in my case. Above OS version M the same file provides flawless streaming.

**Questions that I am looking for the answers are below**

1. Is it Hardware related issue?
2. Is it only OS related issue?
3. Why some of the m3u8 urls working fine on MediaPlayer implementation and some of not?

I am here sharing both the files the First one is working and the second one is not working.

**1. Here is the First URL that working fine : https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8**

One can find the internal details of the file here

```html
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
#EXTM3U

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="stereo",LANGUAGE="en",NAME="English",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="audio/stereo/en/128kbit.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="stereo",LANGUAGE="dubbing",NAME="Dubbing",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="audio/stereo/none/128kbit.m3u8"

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="surround",LANGUAGE="en",NAME="English",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="audio/surround/en/320kbit.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="surround",LANGUAGE="dubbing",NAME="Dubbing",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="audio/stereo/none/128kbit.m3u8"

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="Deutsch",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,FORCED=NO,LANGUAGE="de",URI="subtitles_de.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="English",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,FORCED=NO,LANGUAGE="en",URI="subtitles_en.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="Espanol",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,FORCED=NO,LANGUAGE="es",URI="subtitles_es.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="Français",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,FORCED=NO,LANGUAGE="fr",URI="subtitles_fr.m3u8"

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=258157,CODECS="avc1.4d400d,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="stereo",RESOLUTION=422x180,SUBTITLES="subs"
video/250kbit.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=520929,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="stereo",RESOLUTION=638x272,SUBTITLES="subs"
video/500kbit.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=831270,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="stereo",RESOLUTION=638x272,SUBTITLES="subs"
video/800kbit.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1144430,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="surround",RESOLUTION=958x408,SUBTITLES="subs"
video/1100kbit.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1558322,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="surround",RESOLUTION=1277x554,SUBTITLES="subs"
video/1500kbit.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=4149264,CODECS="avc1.4d4028,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="surround",RESOLUTION=1921x818,SUBTITLES="subs"
video/4000kbit.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=6214307,CODECS="avc1.4d4028,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="surround",RESOLUTION=1921x818,SUBTITLES="subs"
video/6000kbit.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=10285391,CODECS="avc1.4d4033,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="surround",RESOLUTION=4096x1744,SUBTITLES="subs"
video/10000kbit.m3u8
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**2. The content of the NOT WORKING m3u8 file is here as I could not share the URL itself.**

```html
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1790800,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=1790800,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1024x576,FRAME-RATE=29.970,SUBTITLES="subs",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
XXXXXXX/1/XXXXXXX.m3u8
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="English",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,FORCED=NO,LANGUAGE="eng",URI="XXXXXXX/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXX.m3u8"
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Any help, suggestions, feedbacks will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi,Are you solved the issue?

Comment: No man, It seems needs some configuration changes at sever end in m3u8 file. Not sure.